# python json delete first element list or tuple

Tags: python, json, list

This is my part of code:

```
script = soup.find("script", {"id":"product-form-data"})
data = json.loads(script.text)
all_p = data["products"]

for x in all_p.items():
    print(x)
```

I have a problem with this json data. I'm not able to remove everything outside the {} because like this i dont know hot to get id, name and unitsAvailable.

This is my output:

```
(u'193654', {u'unitsAvailable': 2, u'id': 193654, u'name': u'US 10,5'})
(u'193655', {u'unitsAvailable': 1, u'id': 193655, u'name': u'US 11'})
(u'193656', {u'unitsAvailable': 1, u'id': 193656, u'name': u'US 11,5'})
(u'193650', {u'unitsAvailable': 2, u'id': 193650, u'name': u'US 8,5'})
(u'193651', {u'unitsAvailable': 3, u'id': 193651, u'name': u'US 9'})
(u'193652', {u'unitsAvailable': 2, u'id': 193652, u'name': u'US 9,5'})
(u'193653', {u'unitsAvailable': 1, u'id': 193653, u'name': u'US 10'})
(u'193647', {u'unitsAvailable': 1, u'id': 193647, u'name': u'US 7'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `items()` methods you ask the dictionary to return a list of tuple combining the key and its value `(key, value)` [Python Dictionary | items() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/)

To sort key and value, use instead:

```
for key, value in all_p.items():
    print(value)
```